# How do you connect the Blackberry Simulator to BlackBerry Enterprise Server (or Express) for testing?

Tags: blackberry, bes

It seems to be a tricky process. I found some information on the process online but I couldn't find all the information in one place.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the KB article that most people link to that gives an overview of the process:
[Connect_the_BlackBerry_Simulator_to_a_BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server](http://www.blackberry.com/knowledgecenterpublic/livelink.exe/fetch/2000/348583/796557/800738/800792/801083/How_To_-_Connect_the_BlackBerry_Simulator_to_a_BlackBerry_Enterprise_Server.html?nodeid=800986&vernum=0)

Here is a video making the process look pretty simple:
[Java Development - Connecting the Simulator to an Enterprise Server - BlackBerry](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kKdpHgBzB2I)

What isn't mentioned anywhere I've found is that you must allow connections via TCP on port 4101 to your BES server. I don't think it's necessary to forward connections from the outside to your server, but it seems to be necessary when using the BB Simulator.

You get a clue that it's trying to connect on port 4101 if you open the BB Device Manager while it's trying to connect. The BB Device Manager is a program running in the system tray. If you watch the video carefully you'll see him open it one point.